# Receiving binary16 as string in PostMapping then converting to UUID - Spring Boot JAVA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request, uuid

I would like to convert a binary16 string from my request to a UUID. I've tried many approaches, but I haven't made any progress.
The point is that I'm selecting a MySQL database to get this binary16.

If anyone has experience or insights into converting binary16 to UUID or any suggestions on alternative approaches I could try, I would greatly appreciate the assistance. I'm open to any guidance or advice that can help me overcome this obstacle and successfully convert the binary16 data to a UUID format.

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "attendant")
public class AttendantModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Getter
    private UUID attendantID;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Getter @Setter
    private UUID productID1;


    @Column
    @Getter @Setter
    private UUID productID2;


    @Column
    @Getter @Setter
    private UUID instructionID;
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/attendant")
public class AttendantController {
    final AttendantService attendantService;

    public AttendantController(AttendantService attendantService) {
        this.attendantService = attendantService;
    }

    @Autowired
    private AttendantRepository attendantRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveInstructions(@RequestBody @Valid AttendantDto attendantDto) {
        var attendantModel = new AttendantModel();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(attendantDto, attendantModel);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(attendantService.save(attendantModel));
    }
}
```

```java
public class AttendantDto {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;

    @Getter @Setter
    private UUID productID1;

    @Getter @Setter
    private UUID productID2;

    @Getter @Setter
    private UUID instructionID;
}
```

My JSON request is:

```json
{
    "name": "Júlia - vendedora",
    "productID1": "5a61a32a5ab045dbb5a2bf25425da963"
}
```

I tried receiving it in the DTO or Model as a String instead of a UUID, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: Instead of save to the MYSQL as a bynary16, save the UUID as a varchar36.
`@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)`